# Ember control does not come back to loop after sending action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

In my Ember app, I have the following code to remove checked rows dynamically

```
removeRow: function(row){
    // Some logic to remove one row at a time
    var numberContainers = this.get('containers').length;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberContainers; i++){
    }
}

this.get('containers').forEach(function(container){
    if (container.applicable === true){
        var row = {};
        self.send("removeRow", row);
    }
})
```

Now user can select multiple rows & try removing them. With the above code, the "removeRow" action is invoked only once i.e. the forEach loop somehow gets broken or control does not come back again after the "removeRow" action is invoked once.

How can I handle this scenario ?

Comment: i guess you are sure that after the first row is removed; `container.applicable === true` check is still valid (that is something; somehow does not break it). are you sending the action from a component to a controller or from the controller to itself? if the latter is the case; why are you using `self.send` instead of calling `this.removeRow` directly?

Comment: one more question; in sending the action; you are iterating over `containers` not the `rows`? is that true or row and container is the same for your case? sorry if I totally misunderstood the code snippet.

Comment: do you modify `containers` in `removeRow`? Try to do 
`this.get('containers').toArray()forEach(...)`.

Comment: Yes, I am modifying containers in removeRow. Also the toArray() solution seems to me it work...Just wondering what exactly was causing the issue ? Is it because the array modification somehow makes the original calling not work ?

Comment: Also I am sending action within the same component...so it is component A to component A and rows/containers represent almost the same thing...

Comment: then why do you sent the action? Just call a function on `this` if you don't need an action! And its because you can't modify an array within an `forEach` loop. That will just break the loop.

Comment: Wondering any other alternative that I have for this...Anyways it seems to be working with toArray()

Comment: As I have already mentioned and so did @Lux; it is better not use `send` in case you are within  same controller or component. It lessens readability of the code. I cannot think of an alternative with the code snippets provided. good luck.

Comment: Thanks only thing is "removeRow" is defined as an action within that same component...So I am used to using this.send for any action...How does a normal method call work in this case ? Is that built-in Ember feature ?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things were mentioned in comments. You have some different smells and errors:

1. While you're iterating on an array, you are trying to modify it.
2. Instead of calling a function of the component, you are sending an action to call it.
3. It is not clear `var row = {}; self.send("removeRow", row);` If a `container` is suitable why we are removing a newly created `row` object?

Anyway, my suggestions are:

1. Separate the array modification and iteration
2. Define `removeRow` as a function, if you need to use it as an action handler also define an action handler and delegate the whole responsibilty to the function.

Here is a sample code:

```
removeRow: function(row){
    // Some logic to remove one row at a time
    var numberContainers = this.get('containers').length;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberContainers; i++){
    }
}

otherFunction(){
    let applicables = this.get('containers').filterBy('applicable', true);
    applicables.forEach(a=>{let row={};this.removeRow(row);});
}

actions:{
    removeRow(row){
        this.removeRow(row);
    }
}
```